# I'm not able to handle a confimation box for delete

Tags: python, selenium

I have clicked on the ellipses shown in the screenshot attached and a delete confirmation box prompts and I tried to confirm that using `switch_to.alert.accept()` function but error is thrown with

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert exception.
```

Screenshots for the confirmation box and error thrown is attached below:
[Confirmation box for delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXxRR.png)

[Error thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzAMO.png)

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you switching? I do not think that it's an alert. to me, that looks like a simple web element. Are you able to inspect that pop-up?

Comment: @cruisepandey Worked for me. Actually, that was part of the webpage and not an alert. Anyways Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see it's not an alert but a part of the webpage. You have to use find_element() to get the button and click it.